# When I paste a column of numbers using PasteSpecial, it pasts them as text instead of numbers. How do I paste them in number format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a column of numbers in one sheet and paste them to another column in another sheet. When I paste the column of numbers, it pastes them as text even though the format of them in the original sheet is a number. What can I do?

I've tried using a couple different PasteSpecial formattings and I've also tried recording a macro where I convert the format from text to numbers, but neither of these worked.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Worksheets("Data").Activate
        Range("I1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(NumRowsToSkip, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

I expected the column of numbers to be pasted as number, but instead they were pasted as text and it messes up  my equations elsewhere in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Format the destination column as numbers before (or after) pasting and it should hold the formatting...?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, formatting the destination column before pasting doesn't work. I can format the destination column as numbers after pasting and it works, but what's the point of automating it in the first place if I have to go back in and format the columns by hand after?

Comment: All right, I'll post something. you've got a lot of selecting that should be nuked. hang on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of selectiong going on that isn't needed. You should be able to set the formatting before pasting however the below code will automatically format the entire column to be whatever number format you specify in the macro.

```
Sub QuickExample()
'Set your number format the way you want. You can find this in formatting/custom to see whatever you've selected
'The below example is with commas, no decimals, red for negative.
Const YourPreferredNumberFormat As String = "#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)"


    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy

    With Worksheets("Data").Range("I1")
        .Offset(NumRowsToSkip, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .EntireColumn.NumberFormat = YourPreferredNumberFormat
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm definitely trying to work on making my code more clean efficient. I tried this and a couple different variations of this, but I'm still having the same problem! I'll comment back here if I find a solution.